# ADB command to permanently disable Android 12 microphone & camera indicators

Tags: adb, camera, microphone

I want to permanently disable the microphone and camera usage indicator on Android 12.

I tried the following ADB command, but it only disable for some minutes: `adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default`.

I also tried these commands but nothing changes; it only works for some minutes.

```
echo off
adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled 0
PAUSE
adb reboot
(
echo echo off
echo PAUSE
echo adb reboot
)> adbReboot.bat
Enter
adb reboot
```

How to permanently disable these indicators?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is provided by [community member Bose](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/259700):

> ```
> adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default
> adb shell cmd device_config set_sync_disabled_for_tests persistent
> ```
>
> If run in sequence, the second line will disable permanently provided it is Android 13 (on Android 11, this command will not work).